# Python 27 renaming multiple CAD Files

Tags: python, file, rename

I have several (n=1,030) CAD drawing files (.dwg) spread across 51 subdirectories that have the following file naming convention:

(a) 0000-0n-0n.dwg

which needs to be changed to:

(b) _0000_0n_0n.dwg

The original file names (a) comprise three strings, each separated by dashes (-), namely:

a fixed four numeral prefix, followed by n > 1 alphanumeric, then another n> 1 alphanumeric, ending with the .dwg file extension.

The renamed files (b) should preserve these three strings described above, 
but prefix the file name with an underscore and replace the current dashes with underscores as well.
My assumption is that the script works recursively form the parent directory on all .dwg files

I've tried using an os.rename() function but I think I need to put the (a) files into a list and
split them before possibly writing new files with the renaming convention of (b).

If anyone is wondering where this is going - I want these CAD files renamed so they can undergo
a conversion to ESRI feature class format (not shape files), and their geo-database doesn't like
feature class names beginning with numerals (thus the _ prefix), nor does it like dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do. But test it before run please, I just tested the regex expression here, not the whole program.

```
import re
import sys, os

targetfolder = <your CAD file root folder>

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(targetfolder):
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == ".dwg":
            p = re.compile(r'(?P<prefix>\d+)-(?P<mid>\w+)-(?P<last>\w+).dwg')
            m = p.match(f)
            if m:
                newf = '_' + m.group('prefix') + '_' + m.group('mid') + '_' + m.group('last') + '.dwg'
                newfile = os.path.join(root, newf)
                os.rename (os.path.join(root,f), newfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use regular expressions; here is a working example:

```
    import sys, os

    top = "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Temp" # use your own top level directory
    os.chdir(top)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for f in files:
            if f.lower().endswith(".dwg"):
                old = root + "\\" + f
                new = root + "\\_" + f.replace("-","_")
                os.rename(old,new)
```

Comment: I ran both scripts on a subset of DWG files (~ 30) and I get the same error message from both as follows:

  File "G:/gis_data/GEMS/PLANS - Site & Floor/0001 test/rename-DWG01", line 6, in <module>
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(targetfolder):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\os.py", line 284, in walk
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

Can you tell me what this means? Looks like a simple correction but I don't know where to begin editing

Comment: Your input target folder must be escaped or use raw string on Windows. For example, targetfolder = "C:\\YourFolder\\", the above code is wrong on this , and his code will only work under Windows.

Comment: Got a bit further with that modification, but now I've got: File "G:\gis_data\GEMS\PLANS - Site & Floor\0001 test\rename03.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.path.rename(os.path.join(root,f), newfile)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rename'

Comment: Sry. that is my fault, it should be os.rename rather than os.path.rename